# Unable echo a device in /dev on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to echo an LCD screen attached to my system to confirm the device functions correctly. I am running Ubuntu 18.10.

This is the device as per the contents of /var/log/Xorg.0.log:

```
[    15.828] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HID TOUCH HID Touch Panel (/dev/input/event4)
[    15.828] (**) HID TOUCH HID Touch Panel: Applying InputClass "libinput tablet catchall"
[    15.828] (**) HID TOUCH HID Touch Panel: Applying InputClass "Risintech HID touch device"
[    15.828] (II) LoadModule: "risintech"
[    15.829] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/risintech_drv.so
[    15.832] (II) Module risintech: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    15.832]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 2.10.5
[    15.832]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    15.832]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[    15.832] (II) Using input driver 'risintech' for 'HID TOUCH HID Touch Panel'
[    15.892] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event4 13:68 fd 42 paused 0
[    15.892] (**) HID TOUCH HID Touch Panel: always reports core events
[    15.892] (**) risintech: HID TOUCH HID Touch Panel: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
[    15.893] (II) Get Defalt Screen Config
[    15.893] (**) Option "Screen_MaxX1" "4095"
[    15.893] (**) Option "Screen_MinX1" "1204"
[    15.893] (**) Option "Screen_MaxY1" "4095"
[    15.893] (**) Option "Screen_MinY1" "0"
[    15.893] (**) Option "Screen_MaxX2" "1204"
[    15.893] (**) Option "Screen_MinX2" "0"
[    15.893] (**) Option "Screen_MaxY2" "2275"
[    15.893] (**) Option "Screen_MinY2" "0"
[    15.899] (II) [1]1204 4095 0 4095
[    15.899] (II) Init Screen configurtion pass
[    15.899] (--) risintech: HID TOUCH HID Touch Panel: Vendor 0x1bfd Product 0x1688
[    15.899] (II) risintech: HID TOUCH HID Touch Panel: Configuring as tablet
[    15.899] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:03:00.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.0/0003:1BFD:1688.0002/input/input4/event4"
[    15.899] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "HID TOUCH HID Touch Panel" (type: TABLET, id 8)
[    15.899] (II) risintech: HID TOUCH HID Touch Panel: Device Init
[    15.899] (**) Option "Mode" "absolute"
[    15.899] (II) risintech: HID TOUCH HID Touch Panel: initialized for absolute axes.
[    15.899] (**) HID PANEL: Initialize
[    15.899] (**) HID TOUCH HID Touch Panel: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    15.899] (**) HID TOUCH HID Touch Panel: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    15.899] (**) HID TOUCH HID Touch Panel: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    15.899] (**) HID TOUCH HID Touch Panel: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    15.899] (II) risintech: HID TOUCH HID Touch Panel: Device ON
[    15.900] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HID TOUCH HID Touch Panel (/dev/input/mouse1)
[    15.900] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    15.900] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
```

I am unsure from the last few lines whether the device is functioning correctly (even though it appears to be from using a stylus on it).

To confirm I have tried:

```
echo "TESTING TESTING TESTING" > /dev/input/event4
```

However nothing appears on the LCD when I do so. Am I using the correct method to print something to the screen? Does the log all look ok?

This is part of a larger issue I have of trying to get LCDPROC to render on said LCD.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have never added a USB panel so can't give much help.

This looks like Xorg found a touch panel input only without an LCD display by the log. The /dev/input/event4 is an input normally checked with "cat" not "echo".

EDIT: Actually cat would probably show a lot of binary data so better to use "od" for "octal dump" and so get just ASCII.

```
od /dev/input/event4
```

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to write to an input device.

```
Adding input device HID TOUCH HID Touch Panel (/dev/input/event4)
```

is this a touch screen? If so, the specified input might actually be for the touch events on the screen.